# Fast Forward an xrange from Nested Loop Using Dropwhile?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have seen related posts but not quite this question.  I am looking for a way to fast forward an iterator in an outer loop without calling next() in a loop.

The answer may simply be to use the same iterator in the inner loop but I thought there might be a nice way with itertools, I am using dropwhile() but it's not doing what I expected.

So I have a loop inside a loop:

```
cl = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
rangeiter = xrange(0, len(cl))
for x in rangeiter:
    print('{}-'.format(x)),
    for y in xrange(x, len(cl)):
        print('{}'.format(cl[y])),
        if y == 3:
            print
            break
    # fast forward parent range
    rangeiter = dropwhile(lambda v: v < y, rangeiter)
```

I want the outer loop to skip past any indices that the inner loop has processed.  I thought that dropwhile would have done this, but instead I am getting:

```
0- a b c d
1- b c d
2- c d
3- d
4- e
```

when i wanted

```
0- a b c d
4- e
```

[The code is here](http://repl.it/4qz/1).

Thanks!

Comment: `xrange` is not an iterator; it is a *sequence* (so merely an iterable). The `for` loop produces an iterator for it with `iter(iterable)`.

Comment: I see. I assumed that xrange emulated and iterator on it's own (I actually wanted a generator).  Is there a way to advance the internal counter?

Comment: What is the `lambda v: v < x` drop-while condition supposed to do here? `x` is the current value for the outer iterator, so `dropwhile()` will load the next value and that's immediately the next value. For `x = 0`, that mean the next value, `1` is greater, and iteration stops; the outer loop would continue with `x = 2`. Did you mean to advance with `v < y` instead?

Comment: yes, thank you, i just noticed that it should be v < y as well. Is there a way to do it without the iterator so it will run in constant memory or is the iterator smart enough to know what to do with the generator?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'constant memory' here; there is just the one iterator object, it'll not use more memory. `iter(existing_iterator)` returns the iterator itself.

Comment: OK, sounds like a non issue then.  There was an off-chance that the xrange() would be expanded somewhere similar to range()

Comment: No, `xrange()` will never produce a list object. It is a sequence object that materialises values based on index and when iterated, but it won't produce a full list object with all possible numbers in the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop creates an iterator for iterables; `xrange()` is a *sequence* (an iterable), not an iterator.

Create the iterator explicitly, then advance that by using `dropwhile()` (iterating over that object!) to skip elements:

```
cl = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
rangeiter = iter(xrange(0, len(cl)))
for x in rangeiter:
    print('{}-'.format(x)),
    for y in xrange(x, len(cl)):
        print('{}'.format(cl[y])),
        if y == 3:
            print
            break
    # fast forward parent range
    next(dropwhile(lambda v: v < y, rangeiter), None)
```

Note that `dropwhile` I adjusted your `dropwhile` condition to advance based on `y`, not `x`; your expected output suggests you wanted to advance the outer range to beyond where the inner loop had gotten to.

Comment: If you want to skip all of it, you can also throw a StopIteration exception.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: not if you expect that exception to be *caught*. The `for` statement only looks for `StopIteration` raised by the iterator it is looping over, not for the same exception being raised in the loop body.